# Xib designer uses obsolete SetNativeField/GetNativeField method

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xib, visual-studio-2017

Platform: Visual studio 2017
Target: iPad 10.3

We have a Xib with the following code

```
[Foundation.Connect("btnCubicmeterFactor")]
    private UIKit.UIButton btnCubicmeterFactor {
        get {
            this.__mt_btnCubicmeterFactor = ((UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("btnCubicmeterFactor")));
            return this.__mt_btnCubicmeterFactor;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_btnCubicmeterFactor = value;
            this.SetNativeField("btnCubicmeterFactor", value);
        }
    }
```

On building the project we get a warning:
warning CS0618: 'NSObject.SetNativeField(string, NSObject)' is obsolete: 'Do not use; this API does not properly retain/release existing/new values, so leaks and/or crashes may occur.'

When running the application on the iPad crashes do occur. I would love to fix the warning, but i can not find any documentation on how to resolve this issue. The docs at https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/MonoTouch.Foundation/ says so, but no direction on how to resolve.
Has anyone experienced similar problems and or now how to resolve these warnings?

we use these xib to add the control at runtime.

Kind regards,
Rim

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2508) it may be the case that simply switching from `ConnectAttribute` to `OutletAttribute` will solve the double-release that causes the crash, although you will still get the deprecation warnings about `SetNativeField`/`GetNativeField`. e.g.,

```
[Foundation.Outlet("btnCubicmeterFactor")]
private UIKit.UIButton btnCubicmeterFactor { ...etc... }
```

If I read the discussion correctly, the problem is not that `SetNativeField`/`GetNativeField` are fundamentally leaky, but only that when used in conjunction with `ConnectAttribute` they cause double releases.